# Create a user guidance for the tag [mayer-vietoris-sequence]

Tags: discussion, tag-management

Approximately half a year ago I created the tag [mayer-vietoris-sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mayer-vietoris-sequence). By now there are 17 questions with this tag, but so far it has no user guidance.

I do not feel proficient enough to create a guidance myself, but I am sure someone else is.

Comment: Do we really need the tag? Perhaps we do, but why is [algebraic-topology] not enough?

Comment: Write a user guidence (or not), or delete the tag, I dont care. I find it a little bit absurd to ask if the tag [algebraic-topology] is enough, as it is a branch of mathematics, and not really specific.